# Solvability of Neumann boundary problems with singular boundary data $g \in (H^{1})^{*}$

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, harmonic-analysis, elliptic-pde

I have a question on the solvability of Neumann boundary problems with singular data. To state my question, let $\Omega$ be a bounded Lipschitz domain (open and connected) in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

In the case of the Dirichlet problem $$    \triangle u =0\quad \text{in } \Omega \quad \text{and} \quad u=g\quad \text{on } \partial \Omega.$$
 it is proved by [Dahlberg](https://www.impan.pl/pl/wydawnictwa/czasopisma-i-serie-wydawnicze/studia-mathematica/all/66/1/102417/on-the-poisson-integral-for-lipschitz-and-c-1-domains) (1979) that for any $g\in L^{2}(\partial\Omega)$, 
 there exists a unique harmonic function $u$ such that $u\rightarrow g$ nontangentially a.e. on $\partial\Omega$. Also, $u\in H^{1/2}(\Omega)$.

In the case of Neumann problem, 
$$    \triangle u =0\quad \text{in } \Omega \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}=g\quad \text{on } \partial \Omega.$$
it is proved by [Jerison and Kenig](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183548003) (1981) that for any $g\in L^{2}(\partial\Omega)$, there exists a unique harmonic function $u$ such that $\nabla u \cdot \nu \rightarrow g$ nontangentially a.e. on $\partial\Omega$. Also, $u\in H^{3/2}(\Omega)$.

My question is motivated by these results and the result of [Fabes-Mendez-Mitrea](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002212369893316X) (1998).

For $0<s<1$ and $1<p<\infty$, let $B_{s}^{p}(\partial\Omega)$ be a Besov space and define $B_{-s}^{p'}(\partial\Omega) = (B_{s}^{p}(\partial\Omega))^{*}$. They proved that under some condition on $(s,p)$, for any $f\in L^{p}_{s+1/p-2,0}(\Omega)$ and $g \in B^{p}_{-(1-s)}(\partial\Omega)$ satisfying the compatibility condition $\left<f,1 \right>=\left<g,1 \right>$, there exists a solution $u\in L^{p}_{s+1/p}(\Omega)$ of 
$$    \triangle u =f\quad \text{in } \Omega \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}=g\quad \text{on } \partial \Omega$$
in the sense that 
$$-\left<\nabla u, \nabla \phi \right> = \left<f,\phi \right>-\left<g,\mathrm{Tr}\, \phi \right> $$
for all $\phi \in L^{p'}_{1-s+1/p'}(\Omega)$.

My question is the following.

> **Question.** Given $g \in B^{p}_{-1}$, can we find a harmonic function $u$ satisfying the Neumann problem in 'some sense'? Or just $(H^1(\partial\Omega))^*$, i.e., the case when $p=2$.

I cannot find any relevant papers and any comments on this question.

Thank you for your reading.